# Trying to find a short story with ultrasonic keys

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember seeing it in what I think was a collection of sci-fi short stories maybe 20-ish years ago. The only major thing I remember is the early bit where some street kid has really sensitive hearing and can tell the difference between different ultrasonic car keys and tells some adult that he is using the wrong key when trying to unlock a car, and then I think some criminals overhear this and want to use the kid to help steal cars? And then there was maybe a chase/escape down a tunnel.